# Error in catch block

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am working on a desktop application where when I thaught of handling the error in catch block in the Event Log then I am getting a error as

> Error  3   The type or namespace name 'EventLog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

in this

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
    log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
    log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
}
```

waiting for suggestions.

Comment: So "are you missing a 'using' directive or a reference"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to the top:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

or use directly:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application");
    log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
    log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
}
```

or if you're using .NET 3.5 or 4.0 / VS 2008 or 2010 (the most preferred way):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (var log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application") { Source = "MFDBAnalyser" })
    {
        log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

- Keyword `var` reduces the code length.
- You should call `Dispose()` (or use `using` block) for classes implementing `IDisposable`!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `System.dll` has been referenced by your project (normally the case), you can solve this problem by either of :

- Importing the namespace, by adding a `using System.Diagnostics;` directive at the top of your file.
- Qualifying the type fully -  `System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = ...`
- Providing an alias. E.g, by adding `using EventLog = System.Diagnostics.EventLog;` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

have you added a using directive to `System.Diagnostics`?

If not, you will have to write it as `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `EventLog` class library reference to your reference `System.Diagnostics`